# How to run Cisco's webex without installing one of their compromised browser plugins?

Tags: applications, video-conference

After the reports of the [*huge* security flaws](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3160836/software/severe-vulnerability-in-ciscos-webex-extension-for-chrome-leaves-pcs-open-to-easy-attack.html) in Cisco's Webex browser plugins, I've uninstalled all of their browser plugins and would rather run it directly from the command line.

I've figured out that the following *seems* to work for me but it's really brittle:

```
"$HOME/Library/Application Support/WebEx Folder/T31_TC/Training Center.app/Contents/MacOS/Training Center"
```

The big question is how the browser plugins injects the name of the conference or how my authentication information into the WebEx application.

- It doesn't seem to be through environmental variables at least.
- I can't get dtruss to work with it to see what files it is opening.

Anyone figured this out?  Thanks much if so.

**EDIT:**

Aha.  I see the following file that seems to hold a bunch of params.

```
"$HOME/Library/Application Support/WebEx Folder/T31_TC/webexparameters.txt"
```

I see the following entries there:

- Plaintext password (not really _secret).  More Cisco security prowess: 
   `[NAME]-=-oneclickoption-=-[VALUE]-=-4%_secret-=-`
- The conference name in many, many places.  One is: 
   `[NAME]-=-szsiteurl-=-[VALUE]-=-https://companyname.webex.com/conferencename/k2-=-`
- Plaintext email address in many places.

Anyone else gotten farther than I?

Comment: Honestly, if I was forced to use WebEx I'd fire up a virtual machine and run it in there.

Comment: Yeah not a bad idea @py4on.

Comment: Obviously for full effect you need to treat that VM as disposable and not store anything of value on it.

Comment: @Gray The article you linked to shows a screen shot for installing WebEx extension in Chrome, which alternatively offers to 'Run a temporary application to join this meeting'. I haven't had a chance to try it. The VM option is a no-brainer though.